# Remove text between tags w/regex

Tags: java, xml, regex

I am trying to remove the text between tags and add the tags to a String array.

For example: 
< tag1 >< tag2 >remove this< /tag2 >< /tag1 >

I am reading a text document line by line and adding each tag, opening or closing to an array, without the text between but I am having trouble.

I have String[] tags = text.nextLine().split(""); but I am not sure what the regular expression should be to have an array [tag1,tag2,/tag2,/tag1]

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can write this:

```
String[] tags = text.nextLine().split("(?:^|>)[^<]*(?:<|$)");
```

but it's probably safer to use a real XML parser. Note that the above will misbehave if there are any comments `<!-- ... -->` or processing instructions `<? ... ?>` or whatnot, or if one of the tags contains `>` (e.g., `<span title='12 > 11'>`), or in various other cases. Regexes are not a great tool for parsing XML.

---

**Edited to add:** To avoid having an empty first element, you can do a bit of preprocessing to strip out everything before the first tag, and adjust the `split` accordingly:

```
String[] tags = text.nextLine().replaceFirst("^[^<]*<?").split(">[^<]*(?:<|$)");
```

(Note: if `text.nextLine()` doesn't contain any tags at all, then this will result in an array with a single empty element. If you want to get rid of even that, you can do it as a second step after the above:

```
if(tags.size == 1 && tags[0].isEmpty())
    tags = new String[0];
```

)

Comment: Well the point of this assignment is to make my own XML Parser to check the validity of a file using a Stack. The above expression works except that tags[0] is always "". Is there something to get rid of the first empty element?

Comment: @Steve: I've updated my answer to address that.

Answer (score 1):

XML is not a regular language so it cannot be parsed using regular expressions alone. That's fundamental computer science. You are using the wrong tool for the job.

I know this is a student exercise, and students are sometimes set assignments like cracking a nut with a sledgehammer, but the response from any computer professional still has to be that that's not the way to do it.